# How to make a foreign key in EmbeddedId to other Entity with other EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have the class SWEntity that is central to the problem. I want set of classes SWEntityRow that is a detail of the SWEntity (one entity has many rows). The SWentity has in the key two other classes in the embeddedId Area and Procedure. When I try to map SWEntity with SWEntityRow using SWEntityRowId I take differents errors.

Some idea how I can map SWEntityRowId with SWEntity?

This is a simplified picture of the ER: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMJzh.png

And this are my simplified classes:

```
SWentity
-----------
@Entity
public class SWEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SWEntityId id;
    [...]
}


SWEntityId
-------------
@Embeddable
public class SWEntityId implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "areaName", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Area area;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "procedureName", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Procedure procedure;
}


SWEntityRow
---------------
@Entity
public class SWEntityRow{

    @EmbeddedId
    private SWEntityRowId sWEntityRowId;
}

SWEntityRowId
---------------

@Embeddable
public class SWEntityRowId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String rowName;

    //SWEntityId
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="name_row", referencedColumnName="name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="version_row", referencedColumnName="version"),
        @JoinColumn(name="area_row", referencedColumnName="area_name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="procedure_row", referencedColumnName="procedure_name"
    })
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? And can you please post the whole code of the Entities plus the Stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

This resolve my question

```
@ JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="entityname", referencedColumnName="name"),
        @JoinColumn(name="entityversion", referencedColumnName="version"),
        @JoinColumn(name="entityarea", referencedColumnName="AreaName"),
        @JoinColumn(name="entityprocedure", referencedColumnName="ProcedureName")
    })
```

The difference is in referencedColumnName="AreaName" not referencedColumnName="area_name" and the same for procedure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just one change required

```
@Entity 
public class SWEntity {
  @Id
  @EmbeddedId
  private SWEntityId id;
  [...]
}
```

Comment: CORRECT!!! ;)

And I need to change too:
@ ManyToOne
 @ JoinColumns({
        @ JoinColumn(name="entity_row", referencedColumnName="name"),
        @ JoinColumn(name="entity_version", referencedColumnName="version"),
        @ JoinColumn(name="entity_area", referencedColumnName="AreaName"),
        @ JoinColumn(name="entity_procedure", referencedColumnName="ProcedureName")
    })

Comment: sorry but the answer it's not correct like I believe intially. From the EmbbedID:
"There must be only one EmbeddedId annotation and no Id annotation when the EmbeddedId annotation is used.